Suppose a die is rolled repeatedly. Let X be the no. of rolls needed to get all the faces appear for the 1st time. Find the probability mass function.
Let a die be such that $P(\{i\})=P_i, i=1,...,6.$ Suppose the above die is rolled repeatedly and independently. Let $X$ be the no. of rolls needed to get all the faces appear for the 1st time. So, $\text{Min}X=6.$ Find the probability mass function (pmf).
I tried solving the problem as follows:
Let $p$ be the pmf.
If $k$ be the number of times the die needs to be rolled in order to make all the faces appear, then, $$p(k)=P\{X=k\}.$$
If $k\lt 6$ then, $p(k)=0.$
So, let's assume that $k\geq 6.$
Let $E$ be the event that exactly $k$ number of times the die is rolled in order to make all the faces appear.
So, $p(k)=P\{X=k\}=P(E).$
Let $E_i$ be the event that the face $i$ of the die appears at least once in one of those $k$ rolls of the die, where $1\leq i\leq 6.$
Thus, $E=\cap_{i=1}^6 E_i.$
Hence, $P(E)=P(\cap_{i=1}^6E_i)=1-P(\cup_{i=1}^6 E_i^c)=1-(\sum_{i=1}^6P(E_i^c)-\sum_{i_1<i_2}P(E_{i_1}^c\cap E_{i_2}^c)+\sum_{i_1<i_2<i_3}P(E_{i_1}^c\cap E_{i_2}^c \cap E_{i_3}^c)-....+(-1)^5P(E_1\cap E_2\cap ...\cap E_6))\tag 1$
We note that,

$P(E_i^c)=(1-P_i)^k,$

$P(E_{i_1}^c\cap E_{i_2}^c)=(1-(P_{i_1}+P_{i_2}))^k,$ $i_1<i_2$

$P(E_{i_1}^c\cap E_{i_2}^c\cap E_{i_3}^c)=(1-(P_{i_1}+P_{i_2}+P_{i_3}))^k,$ $i_1<i_2<i_3$


$\cdots$

$P(E_1^c\cap\cdots E_6^c)=0.$

Substituting these values in $(1)$ we have,
$$P(E)=P(\cap_{i=1}^6E_i)=1-P(\cup_{i=1}^6 E_i^c)=1-(\sum_{i=1}^6P(E_i^c)-\sum_{i_1<i_2}P(E_{i_1}^c\cap E_{i_2}^c)+\sum_{i_1<i_2<i_3}P(E_{i_1}^c\cap E_{i_2}^c \cap E_{i_3}^c)-....+(-1)^5P(E_1^c\cap E_2^c\cap ...\cap E_6^c))=1-(\sum_{i=1}^6(1-P_i)^k-\sum_{i_1<i_2}(1-(P_{i_1}+P_{i_2}))^k+\sum_{i_1<i_2<i_3}(1-(P_{i_1}+P_{i_2}+P_{i_3}))^k-....+(-1)^5.0)$$
Hence, $$p(k)=1-\big [\sum_{i=1}^6(1-P_i)^k-\sum_{i_1<i_2}(1-(P_{i_1}+P_{i_2}))^k+\sum_{i_1<i_2<i_3}(1-(P_{i_1}+P_{i_2}+P_{i_3}))^k-....+(-1)^4\sum_{i_1<i_2<i_3<i_4<i_5}(1-(P_{i_1}+P_{i_2}+\cdots+P_{i_5}))^k\big ]$$

Is there any way I can improve the readability of the above solution? I want to make it more understandable. Moreover, I do want to know if the solution above has the necessary clarity. Any suggestions regarding these things will be very helpful innmy case. (Lastly, if there are any issues with the solution please do let me know.)

It's should actually be $P(E_i)=1-(1-P_i)^k$ etc, but I don't think you're going about this the right way. Instead consider the problem as a sum of independent random variables, each representing the time taken to get the $k$th new number on the die.

@Wei I made a bad typo. Is it ok now?

As-is, I don't see any logical error remaining. Would be worth plugging in $P_i=\frac16$ to check that you get the right answer in this simple case.
